# Precedence of && vs & in bash and zsh

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Answering [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537298/run-program-from-anywhere-without-changing-directory) I discovered a very funny (and subtle)  difference between behavior in `bash` and `zsh`:

In `bash`:

```
romano@RRyS:~$ pwd
/home/romano
romano@RRyS:~$ alias x="cd /bin && ./echo A >/dev/null  &"
romano@RRyS:~$ x
[1] 16611
romano@RRyS:~$ pwd
/home/romano
```

As you can see, the execution of alias `x` is carried out in a subshell and so the current directory does not change.

Not in `zsh`:

```
[romano:~] % pwd
/home/romano
[romano:~] % alias x="cd /bin && ./echo A >/dev/null &"
[romano:~] % x
[1] 16744
[1]  + 16744 done       ./echo A >/dev/null                                    
1& [romano:/bin] % pwd
/bin
[romano:/bin] %
```

here the directory is changed.

It seems that the `&` in `bash` has a different priority than in `zsh` --- I mean, the command seems to be read as

```
(cd /tmp && echo A) &
```

in `bash` and as

```
cd /tmp && (echo A &)
```

in `zsh`. Is this correct or the cause of the different behavior is another one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Different, documented behavior in `zshmisc`

> A  list is a sequence of zero or more sublists, in which each sublist
>   is terminated by `;`, `&`, `&|`, `&!`, or a newline.  This terminator
>   may optionally be omitted from the last sublist in the list
>          when the list appears as a complex command inside `(...)` or `{...}`.  When a sublist is terminated by `;` or newline, the shell waits for it to finish before executing the next sublist. 
>   If  a  sub‐list  is  terminated by a `&`, `&|`, or `&!`, the shell executes the last pipeline in it in the background, and does not wait
>   for it to finish (note the difference from other shells which execute
>   the
>          whole sublist in the background).  A backgrounded pipeline returns a status of zero.

Answer (score 3):

Buried in `zshmisc(1)` is the following line:

> If a sublist is terminated by a `&',`&|', or  `&!',
>          the shell executes the last pipeline in it in the background,

While it doesn't specifically state that the other pipelines in the sublist are executed in the current shell, that does seem to be what it is implying, and the behavior you observe supports that interpretation. For example:

```
$ echo $foo $bar

$ foo=3 && bar=5 && sleep 1 &
$ echo $foo $bar
3 5
```

also supports the notion at that the first two pipelines execute in the current shell, and only the last pipeline of the sublist actually executes in the background.